# JQuery .load works but not .resize

Tags: jquery, load, resize

So the onLoad part of this function works great, but when I resize the window, it doesn't adjust the heights. With just the onLoad it requires that I refresh the page everytime the window is resized for the div heights to equalize, not sure why .resize isn't working.

Am I making an error?

```
//equalize funciton
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        thisHeight = $(this).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}
```

---

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).load(function() { 
    equalHeight($("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border")); 
}); 
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(window).resize(function() { 
    equalHeight($("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border")); 
});

$(document).ready(function() { 
    equalHeight($("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border")); 
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: not working means is the function calling or not, or is there any error within the `.resize` function ?

Comment: working fine what you really want to happen

Answer (score 1):

```
//equalize funciton
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        thisHeight = $(this).css({'height':'auto'}).height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}

$(window).on('load resize',function() { 
    equalHeight($("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border")); 
});
```

//'on' function requires jQuery 1.7, I guess.

exampleFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/xgYBZ/

Comment: This works great for making the window smaller, but when I drag the window back out I run into the refresh problem again. Sorry for the late reply...

Comment: Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/xgYBZ/1/ it is adjusting fine in both cases, making the window samller or larger. If you can provide a link to the scenario, or a fiddle where the problem exists, we can take a look at it to sort out your issue, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set the height using inline css via script, they will all be the same fixed height before, during and after the resize...the same value that was set on page load. That height is still inline!

You are either going to need to use `removeAttr('style')` if no other inline css exists or wrap the contents of each in another element and check the height of the inner wrap and use that value to set the main elements.

EDIT: try this version that wraps inners and uses those to test height

```
//equalize funciton
function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
        thisHeight = $(this).find('.inner_wrap').height();
        if(thisHeight > tallest) {
            tallest = thisHeight;
        }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
}
$(document).ready(function() { 
    var $group=$("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border")
    $group.wrapInner('<div class="inner_wrap">');   
    equalHeight($group); 
});
```

EDIT: pitfall will be if paddings are different on the various classes in group. If this is the case, either css needs to be changed so padding is on the inner not outer or additional math needs to be added in function.

Comment: Are you trying to say you can't set a new value for height if it's already been set by JS? Not true.

Comment: @Marcel - not saying that at all!  But , height is no longer fluid once it is set inline. That part is absolutely true...until the existing height is removed it is fixed

Answer (score -1):

Replace all your JavaScript you have above with the following:

```
<!-- Include jQuery somewhere up here -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Equalize function
  function equalHeight(group) {
    tallest = 0;
    group.each(function() {
      thisHeight = $(this).height();
      if(thisHeight > tallest) { tallest = thisHeight; }
    });
    group.height(tallest);
  }

  (function($){

    $(window).resize(function() { 
      equalHeight($("#div_right, #div_left, #div_bottom, .border")); 
    }).resize();

  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Does that do the trick?